# Dependency injection and additional functionality

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

this is my general problem so I will boil it down to something very small. Let's have an interface for generic service.

**FIRST PART**

```
public interface IGenericService<T>
{
    void Create(T add);
    void Read();
    void Update(T obj);
    void Delete(T obj);
}
```

And it's implementations:

```
 public class DogService : IGenericService<Dog>
 {
     void Create(Dog add){}
     void Read(){}
     void Update(Dog obj){}
     void Delete(Dog obj){}
 }
```

And second repo which has some unique, additional functionality like Miau()

```
 public class CatService: IGenericService<Cat>
 {
     void Create(Cat add){}
     void Read(){}
     void Update(Cat obj){}
     void Delete(Cat obj){}
     void Miau(){}
 }
```

Now when using some IOC's I would go for:

```
Bind<IGenericService<Dog>,DogService>
Bind<IGenericService<Cat>,CatService>
```

Now somewhere in Viewmodel:

```
public class CatsViewModel
{
    public CatsViewModel(IGenericService<Cat> catService)
    {
        //how to have Miau functionality here?
    }
}
```

1.How can I have Miau functionality here? Should I make second interface for DogService like IDogService and use it this way in here? What is the purpose of generic repo then ?

**SECOND PART** 
Let's have GenericViewModel like this:

```
public abstract class GenericViewModel<T>
{
    T Collection { get; }
    public GenericViewModel(IGenericService<T> service)
    {
        Collection = service.Read();
    }
}
```

And this is fine. But what if I want to use it with CatService

```
public class CatViewModel : GenericViewModel<Cat>
{
    public CatViewModel(IGenericService<T> service) : base(service)
    {
        // make miau here?
    } 
}
```

2. Should I create ICatService interface and inject the instance of the same service with two different interfaces? I know I can cast it from IGenericService since I know what kind of service this is but is it a good approach?

   These questions are about good habits not about solution which just works :)

Comment: What do you mean by "should I create ICatService interface and inject the same instance of service with two different interfaces?"

Comment: Bind<IGenericService<Cat>,CatService>>
Bind<ICatService,CatService>>
And inject both IGenericService<Cat> and ICatService
It doesn't have to be the same instance but instance of the same class :)

Comment: The answer to your question is: you are missing an abstraction. Take a look at [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) to understand what you're missing and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options come to mind:

## Non-generic interfaces

> What is the purpose of generic repo then ?

Indeed, what's the purpose of it? How hard would it be to type out an interface for each purpose?

```
public interface IDogService
{
    void Create(Dog add);
    void Read();
    void Update(Dog obj);
    void Delete(Dog obj);
}

public interface ICatService
{
    void Create(Cat add);
    void Read();
    void Update(Cat obj);
    void Delete(Cat obj);
    void Miau();
}
```

Now each consumer can request the dependency that they need. Clients of `ICatService` can consume `Miau`.

## Pass the extra behaviour as an extra dependency

Another option is to keep the generic `IGenericService<T>`, but add another service for the `Miau` functionality:

```
public interface IMiauService
{
    void Miau();
}
```

Then let the clients that need `IMiauService` request it via their constructors:

```
public class CatsViewModel
{
    private readonly IGenericService<Cat> catService;
    private readonly IMiauService miauService;

    public CatsViewModel(IGenericService<Cat> catService, IMiauService miauService)
    {
        this.catService = catService;
        this.miauService = miauService;
    }

    // Members can use both services as needed...
}
```

This solution hints at a third, and better, option:

## Follow the Dependency Inversion Principle

According to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), the clients should define the API they need, and then it's up to concrete classes to implement that API.

Thus, if a class needs *read* and *write* functionality, it should advertise that need by declaring corresponding interfaces:

```
public interface IReader<T>
{
    T Reader();
}

public interface IWriter<T>
{
    void Write(T item);
}

public class GenericViewModel<T>
{
    private readonly IReader<T> reader;
    private readonly IWriter<T> writer;

    public GenericViewModel(IReader<T> reader, IWriter<T> writer)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    // Members can use the reader and writer services...
}
```

An interface like the OP `IGenericService<T>` smells like something that's been defined before the need was identified, and now you're trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.